# how to create mongoDB objectid in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Refering to post [How to add an array to a MongoDB document using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371839/how-to-add-an-array-to-a-mongodb-document-using-java)
I have created a mongo schema using java
it has sub elements, I am getting `_id` for main document 
I would like to get `_id` in sub elements also here output looks (I have marked the portion where I need `_id`)  `b.party.find().pretty();`

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("5399aba6e4b0ae375bfdca88"),
"addressDetails" : [
    {
        //   _id here
        "locationName" : "Office",
        "phones" : [
            {   //   _id here   
                "name" : "Tel1",
                "value" : "95253-"
            },
            {   //   _id here
                "name" : "Tel2",
                "value" : "95253-"
            },
            {   //   _id here
                "name" : "Tel3",
                "value" : "95253-"
            },
            {   //   _id here
                "name" : "Fax1",
                "value" : "0253-"
            }
        ],
        "address" : "A-3,MIDCA-3,MIDC",
        "defaultBillAddrerss" : "",
        "pincode" : "422 010",
        "city" : null,
        "state" : "1",
        "country" : ""
    },
    {       //   _id here
        "locationName" : "Factory",
        "phones" : [
            {   //   _id here
                "name" : "Tel1",
                "value" : "0253-"
            },
            {   //   _id here
                "name" : "Tel2",
                "value" : "0253-"
            },
            {   //   _id here
                "name" : "Tel3",
                "value" : "0253-"
            },
            {   //   _id here
                "name" : "Fax1",
                "value" : "0253-"
            }
        ],
        "address" : "A-3 INDUSTRIAL AREA,",
        "defaultBillAddrerss" : "",
        "pincode" : "422 010",
        "city" : null,
        "state" : "1",
        "country" : ""
    }
],
"crLimit" : "0.0",
"crPeriod" : "",
"name" : "CROMPTON GREAVES  "
```

}

Java code to create is similar to  [How to add an array to a MongoDB document using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371839/how-to-add-an-array-to-a-mongodb-document-using-java)

Is there any code to create `ObjectId("")` programmatically in java?

Comment: the objectid is created when you insert an object in the database.

Comment: @njzk2 id is automatically created for the parent documents,i am interested in getting id for sub elements

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To create objectId programmatically, use the following syntax

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;


ObjectId id1 = new ObjectId();
ObjectId id2 = ObjectId.get();

// In case you want to mention the parent ID itself,
ObjectId id3 = new ObjectId("5399aba6e4b0ae375bfdca88");
```

Comment: what is the namespace?

Comment: @barrypicker `import org.bson.types.ObjectId;`

Answer (score 1):

To create objectId programmatically, use the following syntax

```
Map<String,String> objectId = new HashMap<String,String>();
objectId.put("$oid","5399aba6e4b0ae375bfdca88");
```

Then insert into mongodb.